# Retrofit2 OAuth 1.0a , POST отправка параметров с пробелами, знаками @#$ и т.д

Tags: android, oauth, retrofit2

Добрый день. 
Отправляю данные по АПИ http://api.ucoz.net/ru/. 
Запрос подписывается oauth 1.0a . Для отправки используется Retrofit2.
В запросе, кроме стандартных параметров oauth (oauth_timestamp, oauth_signature ..) добавлен параметр "fld1". Значением данного поля должен быть любой текст/телефон/емейл.

**Проблема:** если в передаваемом параметре присутствует "пробел", @ # и т.д. - сервер возвращает 401 .

Прошу помочь/направить на истинный путь как отправлять отправлять текстовую строку с протоколом OAauth 1.0a.
Спасибо!

**РЕШЕНИЕ:**
Необходимо было заэкранировать сообщение с помощью URLencode, как подсказали в коментарии, как перед созданием подписи так и перед отправкой на сервер:

```
String encodeMsg = null;
try {     
      encodeMsg = URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

retrofit интерфейс

```
public interface ApiRetrofit {
            @FormUrlEncoded
            @POST("uapi/shop/checkout/")
            Call<Success> postCheckout(@FieldMap(encoded = true) HashMap<String, RequestBody> map);
    }
```

Формирование параметров/подписи:

```
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import com.artmurka.artmurkaapp.BuildConfig;
import com.artmurka.artmurkaapp.Model.Pojo.ItemList.Checkout.OrderDesc;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class UcozApiModule {

    private final String URL = BuildConfig.URL; //artmurka
    private final String CONSUMER_KEY = BuildConfig.CONSUMER_KEY;
    private final String CONSUMER_SECRET = BuildConfig.CONSUMER_SECRET;
    private final String OAUTH_TOKEN = BuildConfig.OAUTH_TOKEN;
    private final String OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = BuildConfig.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET;
    private final String OAUTH_VERSION = BuildConfig.OAUTH_VERSION;
    private final String OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD = BuildConfig.OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD;

    // in PHP -> time();
    //in this method we get current time in SEC, from 1 jan 1970

    private static String getTime() {
        return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    }

    //in PHP -> microtime();

    private static String getMicrotime() {
        long mstime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long right_seconds = mstime / 1000;
        long seconds = mstime / 100000000;
        double decimal = (mstime - (seconds * 100000000)) / 100000000d;
        return decimal + " " + right_seconds;
    }

    //random similar as php -> mt_rand();
    private static String getRandom() {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 1234567890) + 75000000;
        return String.valueOf(x);
    }

    //in this method we get ouath_nonce. MD5(Microtime + random)
    private static String oauth_nonce() {
        String st = getMicrotime() + "" + getRandom();
        MessageDigest messageDigest = null;
        byte[] digest = new byte[0];
        try {
            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            messageDigest.reset();
            messageDigest.update(st.getBytes());
            digest = messageDigest.digest();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, digest);
        String md5Hex = bigInt.toString(16);
        while (md5Hex.length() < 32) {
            md5Hex = "0" + md5Hex;
        }
        return md5Hex;
    }

    /**
     * Создание подписи запроса
     * String method    Метод запроса, например GET
     * string url       URL запроса, например /blog
     * String $params    Все параметры, передаваемые через URL при запросе к API
     * return string
     */

    private String getSignature(String method, String url, TreeMap<String, String> params) {
        String baseString = "";
        try {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                builder.append(entry.getKey() + entry.getValue());
                if (entry.getKey() != params.lastEntry().getKey()){
                    builder.append("&");
                }
            }
            baseString = method + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(URL + url, "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(builder.toString(), "UTF-8");
            Log.d("Log.d", "baseString " + baseString);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String a = "";
        try {
            a = encode(CONSUMER_SECRET + "&" + OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, baseString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return a;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> get(String method, String url, Map<String, String> config) {
        //Map<string, string> config -> MUST have:
        // 'method' ("GET"/"PUT")
        // 'url' in format "uapi/shop/request"
        //'id' or 'page'
        String oauth_nonce = oauth_nonce();
        String time = getTime();

        HashMap<String, String> answerMap = new HashMap<>();
        TreeMap<String,String> list = new TreeMap<>();

        list.put("oauth_consumer_key=",CONSUMER_KEY);
        list.put("oauth_nonce=",oauth_nonce);
        list.put("oauth_signature_method=",OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD);
        list.put("oauth_timestamp=",time);
        list.put("oauth_token=",OAUTH_TOKEN);
        list.put("oauth_version=",OAUTH_VERSION);

        for (String key : config.keySet()) {
            list.put(key+"=", config.get(key));
            answerMap.put(key, config.get(key));
        }

        answerMap.put("oauth_signature", getSignature(method, url, list));
        answerMap.put("oauth_signature_method", OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD);
        answerMap.put("oauth_version", OAUTH_VERSION);
        answerMap.put("oauth_consumer_key", CONSUMER_KEY);
        answerMap.put("oauth_token", OAUTH_TOKEN);
        answerMap.put("oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce);
        answerMap.put("oauth_timestamp", time);

        return answerMap;
    }

    private String encode(String key, String data) throws Exception {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), mac.getAlgorithm());
        mac.init(secret);
        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes());
        String retVal = Base64.encodeToString(digest, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return URLEncoder.encode(retVal, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Формируем данные для отправки, и выполняем запрос.

```
request = new CheckoutRequest();

public void postCheckout(String telephone, String message, String email, String pay, String delivery) {
Call<Success> call = postData(message, pay, delivery);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Success>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Success> call, Response<Success> response) {
Log.d("Log.d", "postCheckout: " + new Gson().toJson(response.code()));
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Success> call, Throwable t) {
}
});





@Override
public Call<Success> postData(String msg, String pay, String delivery) {
UcozApiModule ucoz = new UcozApiModule();
Map<String, String> mapForUcozModule = new TreeMap<>();
mapForUcozModule.put("mode", "order");
mapForUcozModule.put("payment_id", pay); //1 -
mapForUcozModule.put("delivery_id", delivery);
String encodeMsg = null;
        try {
            encodeMsg = URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


mapForUcozModule.put("fld1", encodeMsg); // <<---проблемное )

HashMap<String, String> confForRequest2 = ucoz.get("POST", "uapi/shop/checkout/", mapForUcozModule);
Log.d("Log.d", new Gson().toJson(confForRequest2));

HashMap<String, RequestBody> reqBodyMap = new HashMap<>();
reqBodyMap.put("oauth_signature", createPartFromString(confForRequest2.get("oauth_signature")));
reqBodyMap.put("oauth_signature_method", createPartFromString(confForRequest2.get("oauth_signature_method")));
reqBodyMap.put("oauth_version", createPartFromString(confForRequest2.get("oauth_version")));
reqBodyMap.put("oauth_consumer_key", createPartFromString(confForRequest2.get("oauth_consumer_key")));
reqBodyMap.put("oauth_token", createPartFromString(confForRequest2.get("oauth_token")));
reqBodyMap.put("oauth_nonce", createPartFromString(confForRequest2.get("oauth_nonce")));
reqBodyMap.put("oauth_timestamp", createPartFromString(confForRequest2.get("oauth_timestamp")));

reqBodyMap.put("mode", createPartFromString("order"));
reqBodyMap.put("payment_id", createPartFromString(pay));
reqBodyMap.put("delivery_id", createPartFromString(delivery));
reqBodyMap.put("fld1", createPartFromString(encodeMsg));

return ApiModule.getClient().postCheckout(confForRequest2);
}
@NonNull
private RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {
return RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);
}
```

Модуль Retrofit2

```
public class ApiModule {
    private static ApiRetrofit apiRetrofit;
    public static ApiRetrofit getClient(){
        if (apiRetrofit==null){
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            apiRetrofit = retrofit.create(ApiRetrofit.class);
        }
        return apiRetrofit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам нужно воспользоваться [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) для экранирования значения параметра:

```
String encodedMsg = URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8");
mapForUcozModule.put("fld1", encodedMsg);
```

Comment: Сообщение заэкранировал как перед отправкой на сигнатуру, так и при передаче на сервер. Все отлично. спасибо!